# excel userforms object required error

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in vba in excel 2013 but it still give me error. I try to make it write the info that i provide from the form to an excel sheet but it doesnt work.. Any help welcome...

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

Dim ssheet As Worksheet

Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("testing")

nr = ssheet.Cells(Rown.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1


ssheet.Cells(nr, 1) = CDate(Me.tbDate)
ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = Me.cmbCartridges
ssheet.Cells(nr, 3) = Me.tbQuantity
ssheet.Cells(nr, 4) = Me.tbEuros


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.tbDate = Date

'fill combobox
For Each cell In [CartList]
    Me.cmbCartridges.AddItem cell
Next cell

End Sub
```

[image]

in the debug mode it states that an object required for the following line

```
nr = ssheet.Cells(Rown.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: replace `Rown` with `Rows`

Answer (score 0):

What is Rown?  Are you looking for the sheet rows count?

```
nr = ssheet.Cells(ssheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: `Rown` should be `Rows`, using `(1,1)` does something complety different.

Comment: Then it should be ssheet.Rows.Count?

Comment: well i mispelled.. Although now its working properly.. now it just overwrite every new entry in the first row.. How i can make it to write each entry in a new row?

Comment: I think it should be so, the question is vaque, and doesn't explain anything, but if OP wants to to find first empty row, that's the way to find it.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe he'll expand on the desired results.